# whitespace in R Shiny

Tags: r, whitespace, shinydashboard

I have a problem with text in Shiny Dashboard. I would like to save original text formatting, but shiny removes the whitespaces I want to keep.

```
output$frame <- renderUI({
    HTML(paste(
               p(strong("Name and Surname:"),("     John Smith"))
               )
         )
  })


tabItem(tabName = "aaa",
        h2("bbb"),
        fluidRow(
                box(width = 6, solidHeader = TRUE, htmlOutput("frame")) 
                )
      ),
```

Unfortunately I get `"Name and Surname: John Smith".`
I wish to have `"Name and Surname:     John Smith"`.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Shiny probably doesn’t remove anything. But whitespace in HTML isn’t preserved — that’s just the way HTML works. Use CSS formatting instead of whitespace to align your elements.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `HTML('&nbsp;')` to add 1 whitespace and `HTML('&emsp;')` to add 1 tab space. In your code it wold be as follows:

```
output$frame <- renderUI({
        HTML(paste(
          p(strong("Name and Surname:"), HTML('&nbsp;'),HTML('&nbsp;'),"John Smith")
        )
        )
      })
```

With this you get two white spaces and output looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found that we can also use `stri_dup(intToUtf8(160), 6)` from package `stringi`.

Answer (score 2):

I found this oddly difficult to achieve. Just adding the style element to pre-wrap introduced an extra new line:

```
p(strong("Name and Surname:"),("     John Smith"),style="white-space: pre-wrap")
```

No other style elements (margin:0, etc) could fix this...so,to get around it, I just converted your strong() to HTML, and it works great:

```
p(HTML("<b>Name and Surname:</b>         John Smith"),style="white-space: pre-wrap")
```